# Fix the position of logo - right align css

Tags: html, css

How can I fix the position of logo? The title keeps changing in terms of words so the position changes. I want to fix this logo position, when the text is on new line, the logo needs to go to the same position in the same line.
I have used pull-right class but that's not working probably overridden by some other css.

[image: i]

Comment: if logo is in the same content then you can use `float:right;` or if you use `grid` or `flex` its very easy to do.

Comment: float right is not working, can you please let me know how can I use grid or flex? I am not into htmt but want to do.

Comment: w3school has very good article on these : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp you can start with this.

Comment: Can you provide some more information so that we could help??????

Answer (score 0):

I think the `<a>` element is being made really wide by the padding.
And that's inside `.pull-right` which is floating at the very right of the title.
So you need to get rid of the padding, and align the `.pull-right` to the right of the parent div....
like, put it inside of `.v-card_title`, aligned right, and NOT inside of `.mb-3`
...
hard to say exactly with this little info, it'd be more convenient if you recreated it in a codepen or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your logo these CSS properties

```
img{
position:absolute;
right:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used [flex container](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and moved the title and logo to separate divs. It worked fine